# Unable to execute scheduled tasks in Logoff mode due to OfficeC2RClient.exe and throwing HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)

Tags: c#, office365-apps, windows-task-scheduler

When I tried to execute a scheduled job with my application that writes data inside Excel, so I noticed while executing logoff mode task that time OfficeC2RClient.exe launching in the background, and because of this its throwing Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE). This issue basically occurred with Windows 10 OS (version 1809 or later) and Office 365 ProPlus.

One thing I noticed, if I restart manually "Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service" once and try to execute the same task then OfficeC2RClient.exe not launching and it's working smoothly without any issue, but the thing is I have to do this job every first time after Restart the system also if you schedule a job without logoff mode then also it works fine so the main issue with Scheduler logoff mode.

If you wanted to replicate the same issue at your end then write code for launching the excel file through VBA code script and scheduled that script on logoff mode with the help of "Task Scheduler".

Can you please guide me on how I permanently stopped OfficeC2RClient.exe automatically? or else is there any other way to handle this type of error?

Comment: To be clear, when the user starts logging off you launch Excel? That doesn't sounds like a good idea - what are you trying to do? Are you launching it for the user - in a way that would block the log off? - or in the background, running under some other context? I don't think you can run Excel headless, or at least you're advised against it for Excel Automation.

Comment: I am using Excel for wrote processed data and its working with Scheduler logoff mode as well but the thing is when I try to run the same job with Office 365 Excel version that time I am facing issue because "Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service" auto-launch OfficeC2RClient.exe to checking update version of Excel is available or not. I tried to stopped OfficeC2RClient.exe launching but unfortunately I didn't get any perfect solution and if I restart the "Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service"  then it works fine but I have to do this job every first time of windows login.